# force use of index on complex MongoDB query?

Tags: mongodb

i have a large collection of "messages" with 'to', 'from', 'type', and 'visible_to' fields that I want to query against with a fairly complex query that pulls only the messages to/from a particular user of a particular set of types that are visible to that user.   Here is an actual example:

```
{
  "$and": [
    {
      "$and": [
        {
          "$or": [
            {
              "to": "52f65f592f1d88ebcb00004f"
            },
            {
              "from": "52f65f592f1d88ebcb00004f"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "$or": [
            {
              "type": "command"
            },
            {
              "type": "image"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "$or": [
        {
          "public": true
        },
        {
          "visible_to": "52f65f592f1d88ebcb00004f"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

With indexes:

```
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "n2-mongodb.messages",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "expires" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "n2-mongodb.messages",
        "name" : "expires_1",
        "background" : true,
        "safe" : null
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "from" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "n2-mongodb.messages",
        "name" : "from_1",
        "background" : true,
        "safe" : null
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "type" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "n2-mongodb.messages",
        "name" : "type_1",
        "background" : true,
        "safe" : null
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "ts" : 1,
            "type" : -1
        },
        "ns" : "n2-mongodb.messages",
        "name" : "ts_1_type_-1",
        "background" : true,
        "safe" : null
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "to" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "n2-mongodb.messages",
        "name" : "to_1",
        "background" : true,
        "safe" : null
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "visible_to" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "n2-mongodb.messages",
        "name" : "visible_to_1",
        "background" : true,
        "safe" : null
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "public" : 1,
            "visible_to" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "n2-mongodb.messages",
        "name" : "public_1_visible_to_1"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "to" : 1,
            "from" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "n2-mongodb.messages",
        "name" : "to_1_from_1"
    }
]
```

And here is the explain(true) output from our MongoDB 2.2.2 instance, which looks like a full scan:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 0,
    "nscannedObjects" : 35702,
    "nscanned" : 35702,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 35702,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 35702,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 1,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 85,
    "indexBounds" : {

    },
    "allPlans" : [
        {
            "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
            "n" : 0,
            "nscannedObjects" : 35702,
            "nscanned" : 35702,
            "indexBounds" : {

            }
        }
    ],
    "server" : "XXXXXXXX"
}
```

Looking at the explain output, MongoDB is not using any indexes for this - is there a way to get it to use at least the compound index {to: 1, from: 1} to dramatically narrow the search space?  Or is there a better way to optimize this query?  Or is MongoDB wholly unsuited for a query like this?

Comment: With `$or`, each clause can use its own index. Can you include the output of `explain(true)` for this query and `db.collection.getIndexes()` for this collection? Of your six clauses,  the {to, from} index you suggested would only be useful for one.

Comment: @Stennie remember that nested $ors will not have the optimisations until next release, he is probably using an old release

Comment: So are you saying if I had an index {to:1, from:1} and an index {public:1, visible_to: 1} and an index {type:1} that it would use each of these in the version after 2.4?

Comment: Yes, in 2.6 all these problems with the optimiser are fixed

Comment: Thanks so much for the fast responses - it looks like this isn't available yet however in the 2.5.5 development build - is that correct?

Comment: Correct, in particular see [SERVER-3327: use indexes for nested $or clauses](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3327). The query engine and optimiser has been rewritten in the 2.5 development cycle so there are *lots* of improvements :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query optimizer in MongoDB 2.6 will include support for applying indexes to complex queries.

Answer (score 0):

To force the MongoDB query optimizer to adopt a specific approach, you can use the [$hint](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/hint/) operator.
From the docs,

```
The $hint operator forces the query optimizer to use a specific index to fulfill the query.      Specify the index either by the index name or by document.
```